# Haskell parMap and parallelism

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing, conways-game-of-life

I have an implementation of Conway's Game of Life. I want to speed it up if possible by using parallelism.

```
life :: [(Int, Int)] -> [(Int, Int)]
life cells = map snd . filter rules . freq $ concatMap neighbours cells
    where rules (n, c) = n == 3 || (n == 2 && c `elem` cells)
          freq = map (length &&& head) . group . sort

parLife :: [(Int, Int)] -> [(Int, Int)]
parLife cells = parMap rseq snd . filter rules . freq . concat $ parMap rseq neighbours cells
    where rules (n, c) = n == 3 || (n == 2 && c `elem` cells)
          freq = map (length &&& head) . group . sort

neigbours :: (Int, Int) -> [(Int, Int)]
neighbours (x, y) = [(x + dx, y + dy) | dx <- [-1..1], dy <- [-1..1], dx /= 0 || dy /= 0]
```

in profiling, neighbours accounts for 6.3% of the time spent, so while small I expected a noticable speedup by mapping it in parallel.

I tested with a simple function

```
main = print $ last $ take 200 $ iterate life fPent
    where fPent = [(1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 3)]
```

and compiled the parallel version as

```
ghc --make -O2 -threaded life.hs
```

and ran it as

```
./life +RTS -N3
```

it turns out that the parallel version is slower. Am I using parMap incorrectly here? is this even a case where parallelism can be used?

Comment: Firstly, do you have at least 3 cores in your computer? Secondly, parallelism always comes with some overhead, so if the work being done by each thread is very small, the extra overhead will outweigh any speed-ups.

Comment: i have an i5-2500k, so there is definitely up to 4 cores avaliable

Comment: Note that you can get much larger speedups from improving the algorithm than from parallelising. The bulk of the time is spent in `sort` and `elem`. Using the fact that the list of cells is sorted (and changing `fPent` so that it is sorted) you can roughly halve the time.

Comment: @DanielFischer: the list is not necessarily sorted if fPent is sorted. freq takes the list of every cell neighbouring a live cell as its input, and the same cell could be the neigbour of many different live cells and appear scattered throughout the list. 

If there was a way to be able to find the total number of occurences of each unique element in the list faster than sorting, that would indeed improve the algorithm

Comment: Chris, you sort the list in the step: `freq = map (length &&& head) . group . sort`, so the `cells` for the next generation are always sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're measuring right. Your `parLife` is indeed a bit faster than `life`. In fact, on my machine (Phenom X4, 4 core,) the former only takes about 92.5% of the time the latter does, which considering you're saying you're expecting only a 6% improvement is quite good.

What is your benchmarking setup? Have you tried using [`criterion`](https://github.com/bos/criterion)? Here's what I did:

```
import Criterion
import Criterion.Main

-- your code, minus main

runGame f n = last $ take n $ iterate f fPent
    where fPent = [(1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 3)]

main = defaultMain
    [ bench "No parallelism 200" $ whnf (runGame life)    200
    , bench "Parallelism 200"    $ whnf (runGame parLife) 200 ]
```

Compiled with `ghc --make -O2 -o bench` and ran with `./bench -o bencht.hmtl +RTS -N3`.

[Here's the detailed result of the report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYH0K.jpg).

Comment: Hmm, strange. I also get the result that `parLife` is faster from criterion, but when I run the thing standalone, `parLife` is consistently significantly slower than `life`.

Comment: Ah, only with the threaded runtime, not with the nonthreaded!

Comment: I think it has something to do with the longevity of the process… I.e. initializing the thread pool etc. is more expensive than the (admittedly minor) gains we get from parallelizing.

Comment: Possibly. But I ran with 500 iterations to get more reliable timings. That's long enough that initialising the thread pool etc. shouldn't matter. Probably the threaded runtime has higher overhead for sparking.

Comment: Oh, but wait! The non-threaded runtime doesn't even support parallelism, no sparks there!

Comment: Yeah. It might be worth it to run it through thread-scope to see what's happening exactly. But, as you've suggested further up, there are more obvious points for speeding up this code.